# RabbitMq Direct reply-to aka Fast Rpc with 2 servers

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmq-shovel

Is it possible to configure 2 Rmq servers in order to use
direct [reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) across them?

e.g.

RpcClient connects Server 1 and makes call to RpcServer, which is connected 
to Server 2.

Is it possible to shovel/federate pseudo queue **amq.rabbitmq.reply-to**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to this
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/uFmMgZ91Ptc

This is not possible because *amq.rabbitmq.reply-to*
is not a real queue.